# Is it Safe to Remove gnome-software?

Tags: gnome, gnome-software

I would like to know if it's safe to remove the `gnome-software` package, because it's taking a lot of RAM. I'm not sure if it integrates with the DE or with specific apps.

Is it safe to remove the `gnome-software` package? I have uninstalled `snap-store` before, but sinec gnome-software (deb) is preinstalled I'm not sure if I should uninstall it.

I'm using the standard Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm also using the GNOME DE, preinstalled (as it is in standard Ubuntu 20.04)

Output of `sudo apt remove --simulate gnome-software`

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gnome-software-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv gnome-software-plugin-snap [3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0]
Remv gnome-software [3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0]
```

Comment: Please always [edit] the question to add missing or requested information. Is it the standard Ubuntu (with Gnome)?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I always edit my questions when requested information... Yes It's the standard Ubuntu and yes I'm using the GNOME DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simulated removal shows no dangerous or suspicious issues.

It appears to be safe.

Of course, this means that you won't have the Ubuntu Software application anymore. We don't know if your workflow depends upon it -- only you can know that.

Comment: Yes, I don't use the application, I use the snap terminal package manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default Software Center of Ubuntu in 20.04 and later is the Snap store. On 20.04, Gnome Software may have been installed as well (leading to two "software" icons), but it isn't on any later Ubuntu version. These software stores are graphical user interfaces that in the backend interact with the APT package manager. Snap Store also interacts with the snap system. Gnome Software can be completed with plugins for snap and flatpak support.

So yes, it is perfectly safe to remove either Gnome Software or/and Snap store, even though they may also lead to the removal of the "ubuntu-desktop" metapackage. The latter is a package that depends on all software deemed part of the default Ubuntu desktop. It is used during installation. If at one point desired, you can reinstall it: it would then pull back in any compounds you may have removed yourself.